# django - deleting an object for a specific user from a group of user

Tags: django, django-models

In my app, a user can send message in a thread by creating a new thread or can message to an existing thread. Suppose a user want's to delete a message from a particular thread, I can probably delete the message. But I just want to delete the message for that user, and not for the other users of that thread. So that the message will only be seen to the other users other that the user who deleted it. How do I do that?

models.py:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

**Edit:**

message.html:

```
<div id="conversation">
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message|is_visible:request.user %}
            <div class="messages">
                <p>{{message.body}}</p>
                <p>{{message.sent_date}}</p>
                <p>-{{message.user}}</p>
                <hr>
           </div>
        {% else %}
           <div class="messages">
               <p>You have deleted this message.</p>
           </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**Edit:**

templatetag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def is_visible(message, user):
    """Check the user's visibility of the message."""
    return not HideMessage.objects.filter(message=message, user=user).exists()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually want to delete the message, but rather hide it from a specific user. The way to do this could be to have your threads/messages visible by all by default, but when the user "deletes" the message, create an instance of a `HideMessage` model or similar that links the message to the user that "deleted" it. Then you could create a simple template filter that checks the currently logged in user (`{{ request.user }}` in the template) against the message to see if they have visibility of it, e.g.

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if message|is_visible:user %} {# your custom filter #}
        <div class="msg visible">
            Message stuff here
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <div class="msg hidden">
            You have hidden this message!
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `HideMessage` model for example might only need:

```
class HideMessage(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

You create an instance of this whenever your user hides a specific message, and you check for the existence of this in your filter to determine if the user can see a message.

The django documentation is very good on [template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), and is worth a read. A very quick implementation though would be along the lines of:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def is_visible(message, user):
    """Check the user's visibility of the message."""
    return not HideMessage.objects.filter(message=message, user=user).exists()
```

Comment: Do, I create a new class model to hold that?

Comment: Thank you so much! But I am not so familiar with the template tags... Could you please kindly show me how it would be. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tags too. And I am really trying to figure it out, but all I am getting is `You have deleted this message.` in the template. I have edited and added my html. Where am I doing wrong......

Comment: Its just the same as you told me. I have added it.

Comment: And you have no `HideMessage` records at all in your database? Strange, I will try it out myself in a while.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42348/discussion-between-pete-tinkler-and-aamu)